# Type __u64 could not be resolved / #if defined(__GNUC__)

Tags: c, eclipse

I have C  project for Android in Eclipse which is giving the error: `Type '__u64' could not be resolved.`
And `__u64` appears as a greyed out type in the list beneath the relevant `types.h` file in the includes folder.

It seems that this problem is because the relevant type definition in the header file is preceded by `#if defined (__GNUC__)`.

Fortunately the project builds OK (so is this an issue with Eclipse parser rather than Eclipse generator).

How do I get rid of the annoying error message?

EDIT . . .

Yes, the code is using `__u64`. It does what is required and the code works. My problem is not with the code. My problem is with Eclipse configuration.

I believe the Eclipse compiler (GNU C) sees the following (in `types.h`) -
`#if defined(__GNUC__)`
**`typedef`** *`typedeclaration`*
`#endif`
- passes the test, and accepts the declared data type.
But the Eclipse parser doesn't.

So how do I configure Eclipse so that the parser also passes the `#if defined(__GNUC__)` test and, in this instance, accepts `__u64` as a legitimate data type.

Comment: Is your code using `__u64` anywhere?  If not, it should be a non-issue.  If it is, why?  The `__` (double underscore prefix) indicates it is a name reserved for the implementation; you should not normally use such names yourself — it would be very unusual for user code to use it (a different matter if you're implementing the system, though, but you'd know if you were doing that).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The *name* is reserved for the implementation yes - that means you shouldn't *define things with that name* but it *doesn't mean* you shouldn't use things with that name defined by the implementation. This particular implementation defines it as a 64-bit unsigned integral type that anyone can use.

Comment: @immibis: The name that normal user code should use, then, is `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>`.  Using `__u64` inherently limits the portability of the code using it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That is correct (in 2016), but it doesn't mean using `__u64` is *wrong*.

Comment: That's why I said "you should not normally use such names" in my original comment — covering the case where you might for some reason decide that the abnormal applies to your code.  I'm not sure what we're arguing about; I covered the base in the first place.

Comment: People, although I'm grateful for the guidance on which names I should or should not be using, you're missing the point. 

Let me present the problem another way: If, for example, you need to know whether or not your program is being compiled by GCC, or by a non-GCC compiler that claims to accept GNU-C dialects, you can simply test \__GNUC__. The eclipse compiler will pass the test but the Eclipse parser doesn't appear to and, as in the specific example in the original post, can throw an error as a result. Is it possible to configure Eclipse parsing to overcome this anomaly.